# Canvas not updating after each loop iteration

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I made a little javascript Newton fractal grapher. I have two loops iterating over each pixel on a canvas, but the image only appears once the whole canvas has been iterated over. What gives?

My code below. Although the math might be a little confusing, with calculus, complex numbers and all, I'm sure the code itself is easy to follow (although clearly not optimized.) The function you probably want to look at is cGraph.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Newton Fractal Grapher</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="700" ></canvas>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var winWidth = document.getElementById("myCanvas").clientWidth;
var winHeight = document.getElementById("myCanvas").clientHeight
var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");

function cAdd(a,b) {return [a[0]+b[0],a[1]+b[1]];}

function cSubtract(a,b) {return [a[0]-b[0],a[1]-b[1]];}

function cMultiply(a,b) {return [a[0]*b[0]-a[1]*b[1],a[1]*b[0]+a[0]*b[1]];}

function cDivide(a,b) {return [ (a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1])/(b[0]*b[0]+b[1]*b[1]) , (a[1]*b[0]-a[0]*b[1])/(b[0]*b[0]+b[1]*b[1]) ];}

function cExp(a,b) {
var x = a;
for (var i = 1; i < b; i++)
x = cMultiply(x,a);
return x;
}

var graphXmin = -1.1;
var graphXmax = 1.1;
var graphYmin = -1.1;
var graphYmax = 1.1;
var graphZmin = -1;
var graphZmax = 1;
var graphX;
var graphY;
var graphZ;

function cGraph(func)
{
    var z = [0,0];
    for (var x=0; x<winWidth; x++)
        for (var y=0; y<winHeight; y++)
        {
            graphX = (x/winWidth)*(graphXmax - graphXmin)+ graphXmin;
            graphY = (y/winHeight)*(graphYmax - graphYmin)+ graphYmin;
            graphZ = func([graphX,graphY]);
            z[0] = Math.round(    (graphZ[0]-graphZmin)/(graphZmax-graphZmin)*255    );
            z[1] = Math.round(    (graphZ[1]-graphZmin)/(graphZmax-graphZmin)*255    );
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+z[0]+","+(255-[z[1]])+",0)";
            ctx.fillRect(x, winHeight-y, 1, 1);
        }
}

function cCube(x) {return cSubtract(  cExp(x,3)  ,[1,0])}

function cFive(x) {return cSubtract( cExp(x,5) , [1,0]) }

function cEight(x) {return   cSubtract(      cAdd( cExp(x,8)  , cMultiply(cExp(x,4) ,[0,4]) )     ,      [16,0] )}

function cDeriv(x,func) {
    return cDivide(
        cSubtract(
            func(  cAdd(x,[.0001,0])  ),
            func(  cSubtract(x,[.0001,0])  )
        ),
        [.0002,0]
    )
}

function cNewton(x,func)
{
    for (count = 0; count < 500; count++)
    {
        x = cSubtract( x,cDivide(func(x), cDeriv(x,func)));
        if (func(x)[0] < 0.001 && func(x)[0] > -0.001)
            return x;
    }
    return [255,255];
}

cGraph(   function(x){return cNewton(x,cFive)}   );

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser waits until all scripts finish running before it repaints the screen. So all the for loops you have have to complete before anything will show up.

So what you want to do is break the for loops into `setTimeout`s or `setIntervals` so that the browser will repaint in between each one and you can see the result.

This fiddle shows in in action http://jsfiddle.net/Mw3WB/

everything stays the same execpt for the graph function

```
function cGraph(func)
{
  var z = [0,0];
  var x = 0;

   var outer = setInterval(function(){
     if(x>= winWidth){
      clearInterval(outer);   
     }
     else{
       for (var y=0; y<winHeight; y++)
       {
        graphX = (x/winWidth)*(graphXmax - graphXmin)+ graphXmin;
        graphY = (y/winHeight)*(graphYmax - graphYmin)+ graphYmin;
        graphZ = func([graphX,graphY]);
        z[0] = Math.round(    (graphZ[0]-graphZmin)/(graphZmax-graphZmin)*255    );
        z[1] = Math.round(    (graphZ[1]-graphZmin)/(graphZmax-graphZmin)*255    );
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+z[0]+","+(255-[z[1]])+",0)";
        ctx.fillRect(x, winHeight-y, 1, 1);
       }
       x++
    }
  },20);


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Was 20 milliseconds arbitrary? Any reason not to put 0?

Comment: It is completely arbitrary.